# Handeling many-to-many as multiple one-to-one when read

Tags: sql

Is there a way to handle a one-to-many relationship as if they would be multiple one-to-one entries?

For all users I have to display all the tasks that are assigned to them in a list, sorted by user, but when a task is assigned to multiple users I have to display it multiple times in the list.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. A one-to-one is usually mapped as attribute to an entity, a one-to-many as list. Do you propose to add an unspecified number of attributes to an object, depending on how many there would be in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand it well, you have User (0,n) ----- (0,n) Task
So you should have in the physical implementation :
User(0,n) ----- (1,n)User_to_Task(1,n) ----- (0,n)Task
Then you just have to select from the User_to_Task table to have like a multiple one-to-one relationship:

```
SELECT * FROM User_to_Task
JOIN User ON USE_Id = UTT_USE_Id
JOIN Task ON TAS_Id = UTT_TAS_Id
ORDER BY USE_Id
```